# Ionic - Android: native scroll get stuck at some point

Tags: scroll, webview, ionic-framework, android-webview, infinite-scroll

Due to performance issues I've change our wall scrolling to use native scrolling (overflow-scroll) instead of js scrolling. (The infinite scroll is working)

The performance is somewhat better but here is the weird thing:
In android, when I scroll down, it just doesn't scroll down after some scrolling  (scroll back up is working). When I do something like opening and closing the statusbar of the physical/simulator phone, then it is working again.

I guess it something related to the element refresh of the android WebView, any idea?

Comment: Try using crosswalk. I faced a similar problem. I installed crosswalk and changed my ionic library to nightly build.

Comment: I've tried to install crosswalk many times, never succeeded... always got a build error...

Comment: any update on this???

Comment: I get the same issue using Ionic 2. Also, the spinner does not turn off at the last result set.